# Looping through an array in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, swiftui

I have an array of strings I want to loop through and create a view for each element. To achieve that, I tried using `ForEach()`, the output of the code below are the following errors:

`Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Binding<C>'`

`Generic parameter 'C' could not be inferred`

**Code**:

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    let array: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(array, id: \.self) { letter in
                Text(array[letter])
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

PS: The code is simplified

**Desired output**:

VStack of all letters from the array

Comment: `Text(letter)` only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this (just use the `letter` parameter from the for loop):

```swift
let array: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(array, id: \.self) { letter in
            Text(letter)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: @scrap_tech_guy, just to be clear about why the above code sample posted by @blackjacx works, it's because `letter` itself will be an `element` of `array`. Therefore, it's not supposed to be used as an *index* to access an element of the array - you just use it straight - as it **is** the element itself.

Comment: @scrap_tech_guy, another thing you *could* have done - but that would have been worse in this specific case than what @blackjacx is doing in his code sample - is: `ForEach(array.indices, id: \.self) { index in Text(array[index]) }` :).

Comment: Thank you for further explanation Ɛ>